# Subtract values from sum depending on the value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a mysql table with columns:

```
value - integer
type  - integer
```

`value` only can be positive integer, `type` can be `0` or `1`

I need to sum this `value`, but the thing is that if `type` value is `1` i need to subtract this row `value` from my sum.

Is its possible to make without two queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this, using `if`:

```
sum( if(`type` = 1, -1, 1) * `value` )
```

Or `case`:

```
sum( (case when `type` = 1 then -1 else 1 end) * `value` )
```